# I have a small bug in my Web Gallery, When ever a name of Artist is big it messed up the mobile layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

hello i have an online gallery which is used to show artists. The problem is it is good on computer now but when ever i change the name of an artist and the name is big it will messed up layout on mobile.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .col {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .container .row {
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
  }
  
  .container .row .col {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container .row .col {
      min-height: 580px;
    }
  }
  
  .profile_card {
    border: 3px solid #222;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_image > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transition: all 0.50s linear 0s;
  }
  
  .profile_card:hover .profile_image img {
    transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content h3 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #9BA34D;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content h3 > span {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content .social_links {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content .social_links li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content .social_links li a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.50s linear 0s;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content .social_links li a:hover {
    background: #8E9545;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content .read_more {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #9BA34D;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  
  .profile_card .profile_content .read_more > i {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5F6332;
    animation: slideInRight 1s ease-in-out 2s infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes slideInRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    30% {
      transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    60% {
      transform: translateX(15px);
    }
    90% {
      transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
  }
  
  .image-overlay .image-overlay-inside {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .image-overlay {
    display: none;
    background: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Silento.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Silentó<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Tony-Yayo.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Tony Yayo<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Salvo-Riggi.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Salvo Riggi<span>DJ / Music Producer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Natalia-Itani.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Natalia Itani<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Claudia-Valentina.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Claudia Valentina<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Alain-Sceciall.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Alain Scecial<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nessi-Anshal.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Nessi Anshal<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col">
      <div class="profile_card">
        <div class="profile_image">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://gtrrecordingstudio.com/gtr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Njimbam-Musica.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile_content">
          <h3>Njimbam Musica<span>Singer</span></h3>
          <ul class="social_links">
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="read_more">read more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please  try this:

```
.profile_content h3{max-width:180px;word-break:break-word}
```